# What does this function do in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to python.

```
def maintain_delta(new_vals, host, action):
    file_name = build_file_name(host, action)
    err, data = read_values(file_name)
    old_vals = data.split(';')
    new_vals = [str(int(time.time()))] + new_vals
    delta = None
    try:
        err, delta= calc_delta(old_vals, new_vals)
    except:
        err = 2
    write_res = write_values(file_name, ";".join(str(x) for x in new_vals))
    return err + write_res, delta
```

source github [link](https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb/blob/master/check_mongodb.py):

From what I understand, it reads data from a file and adds `time.time()` function to get the new val. What does `time.time()` do? Does this function generate a file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/index.html)

[time.time()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?highlight=time.time#time.time)

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.
>   Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point
>   number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1
>   second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it
>   can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has
>   been set back between the two calls.

It's worth bookmarking the docs, I refer to them many times a day. You'll be able to answer these types of questions easily.

As @redrah reminds us in a helpful comment below, accessing `help()` from inside the Python shell also offers some useful immediate on-line information about various functions.

Comment: It's worth noting as well that the builtin function `help()` is another useful way of getting information like this.  `>>>help(time.time) 
time(...)
    time() -> floating point number

    Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch.
    Fractions of a second may be present if the system clock provides them.`

Comment: @redrah Good point ... I'll update the answer with a reference to this

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time):

`time.time()`
Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.